# Running Pymol console commands through Bash script

Tags: bash, pymol

I want to run commands in the pymol console through a bash script.How can i do it? Below is my code but it is not working.

```
#!/bin/bash
##
## PyMOL startup script
##

# Set PYMOL_PATH to point to this directory
export PYMOL_PATH="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"

# other environment variables
export PYTHONHOME=$PYMOL_PATH/ext
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONHOME/lib/python2.7:$PYTHONHOME/lib/python2.7 /lib-tk:$PYTHONPATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PYMOL_PATH/ext/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LANG=C

# binary executable
exec $PYMOL_PATH/pymol.exe "$@"
exec cmd.load("1a4g.pdb") 
exec cmd.quit()
```

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). It's a bad idea to try to use bash to type into an interactive console, if I understood correctly.

Comment: Then what should i do? i need to automate a pymol plugin for 200 proteins.How can i do it?

Comment: I don't know PyMOL, but I suppose there should be a batch option.

Answer (score 3):

You can just make a PyMOL script in your bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

$PROT1="1a4g"
$PROT2="1ogg"

#create the script
echo "fetch $PROT1
fetch $PROT2
select *" > script.pml

# GO!
pymol script.pml
```

Alternatively, if you want to start a script from within pymol itself ([PyMOL wiki](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Running_Scripts))